# Aws Lamda functions missing and not allowing to create new functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Suddenly lamda functions in my aws account are missing. and when i try to create new functions create function button keeps loading..

[image]

[image: I can see the link to lamdas in api gateway but when i click on them it loads a blank function]

[image]

Comment: login logout, and verify that you are in the right region when viewing your lambdas

Comment: Whenever strange things happen in the browser like that red box, it's a good idea to Quit & restart your browser, or even reboot your computer. That "last fetched 53 years ago" message is a little worrying -- also check the clock on your computer to make sure it is set correctly.

Comment: Tried from 2 different browsers and 2 laptops same thing.